# how to display a message when a product is added or removed from the cart in django

Tags: python, html, django, e-commerce

I am doing an ecommerce with django and I want to add a message when they add or remove a product, but I don't know where to put it or how, I am using the message framework.
The messages work only that I don't know how to add them so they appear when I delete or add a product to the cart.

I show you my simplified code

views.py

```
def store(request):
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

def cart(request):
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']
     
    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

def updateItem(request):
    data =json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']

    print('Action', action)
    print('Product',productId)
    customer=request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)
    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
        messages.success(request, 'the product was added successfully')
       
    if action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)
    orderItem.save()
        
    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()

    elif action == 'delete':
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

In order not to repeat the code several times, I created a utils.py file that is related to the view.
utils.py

```
def cookieCart(request):

    #Create empty cart for now for non-logged in user
    try:
        cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
    except:
        cart = {}
        print('CART:', cart)

    items = []
    order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
    cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    for i in cart:
       
        try:
            cartItems += cart[i]['quantity']

            product = Product.objects.get(id=i)
            total = (product.price * cart[i]['quantity'])

            order['get_cart_total'] += total
            order['get_cart_items'] += cart[i]['quantity']
            

            item = {
                'id':product.id,
                'product':{'id':product.id,'name':product.name, 'price':product.price, 
                'imageURL':product.imageURL}, 'quantity':cart[i]['quantity'],
                'get_total':total,
                }
            items.append(item)

        except:
            pass
            
    return {'cartItems':cartItems ,'order':order, 'items':items}

def cartData(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
        messages.success(request, 'Your profile is updated successfully!')
    else:
        cookieData = cookieCart(request)
        cartItems = cookieData['cartItems']
        order = cookieData['order']
        items = cookieData['items']
        


    return {'cartItems':cartItems ,'order':order, 'items':items}

    
def guestOrder(request, data):
    name = data['form']['name']
    email = data['form']['email']

    cookieData = cookieCart(request)
    items = cookieData['items']

    customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(
            email=email,
            )
    customer.name = name
    customer.save()


    order = Order.objects.create(
        customer=customer,
        complete=False,
        )

    for item in items:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=item['id'])
        orderItem = OrderItem.objects.create(
            product=product,
            order=order,
            quantity=item['quantity'],
        )
    return customer, order
```

Comment: If you don't know how to display messages in your templates then have a look at [django docs about displaying messages.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages)

Comment: looks like you need javascript to read your json response, or return a template with the message added to the context

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use django messages then return the template instead of Jsonresponse. or if you want to send message by using jsonresponse then follow this..

**views.py:**

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
import json

def updateItem(request):
    data =json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']

    print('Action', action)
    print('Product',productId)
    customer=request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)
    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
        message = "Added"
       
    if action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)
        orderItem.save()
        message = "Remove"
        
    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()
        message = "Remove"

    elif action == 'delete':
        orderItem.delete()
        message = "Delete"

    ctx = {'message': message}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx),content_type='application/json')
```

**In your html**

```
<script>
    ....
      $.ajax({
       ......
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
          icon(response);
        },
        error: function (rs, e) {
          alert(rs.responseText);

        }
      });
      
      function icon(response){
        if (response.message === 'Added') {
            //fetch the div id and saw msg 
        };
        if (response.message === 'Delete') {
            //fetch the div id and saw msg 
        };

        if (response.message === 'Remove') {
            //fetch the div id and saw msg
        };
      ......
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your template or html, end of the html u just need to add this code.

```
{% block include_js %}

{% if success %}
<ul class="messages" >
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            swal('{{ success }}');
    </script>
</ul>
{% endif %}

{% endblock include_js %}
```

Comment: messages.success(request, 'the product was added successfully')
and ----------------------------------------------

messages.error(request, 'the product was removed successfully')